# Adding predictors in ROC curves and how does it affect AUC?

Tags: prediction, roc, auc

I have a general question about ROC curves and how adding predictors affect AUC values.

- Let's say I have a model that contains only predictor A and produces an AUC of 0.6.
- I then add into the model a predictor B that produces an AUC 0.7.
- I further then add a predictor C into the model (A + B + C) and an AUC of 0.8 is produced.

My question is, if I only had a model of A + C, can it be assumed that the AUC will be less than 0.7 (eg, the model with A + B)?

Or is it possible that the model of A + C could have generated a AUC of say 0.75? If this is true, could it be suggested that predictor variable B is less valuable than variable C in prediction modelling?

Comment: Can you specify the time of model you're using? Answering this question will depend entirely on what model and what type of data you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this is true, could it be suggested that predictor variable B is
>   less valuable than variable C in prediction modelling?

AUC of a ROC curve might not be the best way to check which predictor variable is more or less valuable. The curve is based on ranking instances. Adding a variable that slightly changes the probabilities of a model could result in a completely different ranking.

> My question is, if I only had a model of A + C, can it be assumed that the AUC will be less than 0.7 (eg, the model with A + B)?
>   Or is it possible that the model of A + C could have generated a AUC of say 0.75?

Generally speaking, it's harder to improve an AUC from 0.7 to 0.8 than from 0.6 to 0.7. The information that B and C share might affect the results as well.

Apart from the fact that AUC is not a proper metric for this argument, you can suggest that C contains more information for the given task. Adding C probably leads to 0.70+ not 0.70- AUC (e.g. mutual information in B and C).